# How to replace sts.LinearRegression with non-linear model for a Tensorflow Probability Structured Time Series model component

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, forecasting, tensorflow-probability

I'm creating a time-series forecasting model with external, controllable features similar to the "Forecasting Demand for Electricity" example found at https://medium.com/tensorflow/structural-time-series-modeling-in-tensorflow-probability-344edac24083. In order to model the influence of the external factors, I am using an sts.LinearRegression() as a component of my model, but those external factors are very non-linear in nature and it's causing unwanted negative predictions in my model.

I've tried creating (simpler) forecasting outside of TFP STS, and found that a RandomForestRegressor works much better a LinearRegressor for these external features. What I'd LIKE to do is replace the sts.LinearRegression() with an sts.RandomForestRegressor(), but that isn't available from the sts library. In fact, there are hardly any options available from the sts library: https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/sts/LinearRegression

I've also tried converting my target variable to log form, but there are numerous instances of zeros (which are inf for log), and this doesn't turn out to be a useful transformation.

My model architecture for TFP STS looks something like this:

def build_model(observed_time_series):

```
season_effect = sts.Seasonal(
                num_seasons = 4, num_steps_per_season = 13, observed_time_series = observed_time_series,
                name = 'season_effect')
marketing_effect = sts.LinearRegression(
                design_matrix = tf.stack([recent_publicity - np.mean(recent_publicity),
                active_ad - np.mean(active_ad)], axis = -1),
                name = 'marketing_effect')
autoregressive = sts.Autoregressive(order=1,
                observed_time_series = observed_time_series,
                name = 'autoregressive')
model = sts.Sum([season_effect,
                 marketing_effect,
                 autoregressive],
                 observed_time_series = observed_time_series)
return model
```

Where I want to change the "marketing_effect" component of the model to something non-linear.

Is my only option here to clone the TFP STS library and create a custom function to handle non-linear data with something like a Random Forest Regressor? Does anyone know of a better option?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the usage of random forests in sts models. Can you point to a system where this exists? The trick with tfp.sts is that the math all works out nice & analytically because everything is marginally gaussian. If we can make that work, I think we're definitely open to bringing in other models.

Comment: I guess this is a nice link: https://towardsdatascience.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-using-random-forest-2372f3ecbad1

Comment: Brian, 
Thanks for your feedback. the random forest was mainly meant to be an example of a non-linear model that does not provide negative predictions (on a necessarily positive target variable). Is there a way to constrain the Linear Regression to give positive output?

Comment: Sometimes folks will layer an observation model over the sts model, e.g. I've heard of parameterizing a poisson. You might try tfp.JointDistributionNamed to specify first the sts tfd.LinearGaussianStateSpaceModel then pass it's samples as the parameter of a downstream exponential family, perhaps exponential for your positive case?

Comment: Here's an example, I haven't read it too deeply. https://www.jstor.org/stable/1391639?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents